# socket.io not connecting in aws server

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

i have node js express project.
I m implementing socket.io for chat applications.
To check Socket connection, i m using this tool.
https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/

This is my server code.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const compression = require('compression');
const logger = require('./components/helper/logger');
const multer = require('multer');
// const uuidV4 = require('uuid/v4');
const moment = require("moment");
const fs = require('fs')
const cors = require("cors");

const clientAuthentication = require('./middleware/clientAuthentication');

const config = require('./config/config');


const app = express();
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
const port = config.host.port || "3001";
app.set("port", port);
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(cors());


//////////////////////socket/////////
var io = require("socket.io")(server,{
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    },
  });

// var socketmodule = require('./components/chat/socketmodule')(io)


//added temp
const {joinUser, removeUser, findUser} = require('./components/chat/users');

let thisRoom = "";
    io.on("connection", function (socket) {
        console.log("connected");
        socket.on("join room", (data) => {
            console.log('in room');
            
            let Newuser = joinUser(socket.id, data.username, data.roomName)
            socket.emit('send data', { id: socket.id, username: Newuser.username, roomname: Newuser.roomname });

            thisRoom = Newuser.roomname;
            console.log(Newuser);
            socket.join(Newuser.roomname);
        });
        socket.on("chat message", (data) => {
            io.to(thisRoom).emit("chat message", { data: data, id: socket.id });
        });
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            const user = removeUser(socket.id);
            console.log(user);
            if (user) {
                console.log(user.username + ' has left');
            }
            console.log("disconnected");

        });

        
    });

//added temp

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/chatTest.html");
});
////////////////////socket///////


server.listen(port);
logger.info(config.host.url);
logger.info("API server started on: " + port);
```

I checked the connection using above tool. like http://localhost:3000, and socket connected.
But when I check it in server, its not working.

I m using ngnix server in server and to map my port i m doing reverse proxy like

```
location /hiyup_dev/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
```

I checked like
http://example.com/hiyup_dev (it will point to port 3001) its not working.

Then i added my port in inbound aws rules.
Then i checked like
http://myip:3001  it also not working.

What i am missing here. It works fine in local not in server. :(

Answer (score 1):

The Problem with the Client-side(swift) integration. It supports only socket version2+/3+. So i downgraded server socket version from 4 to 3. and i got it worked.